# Assigning multiple attributes with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, radio-button, spree

Im building a plugin to spree, that i need in my application. We are using a shipping company that doesn't deliver to private adresses but to some parcel shops around the country. So when the user comes to the delivery step in the checkout, will he/she have to choose among a number of places where he/she can pick up the delivery.

My problem is that i want to let the user choose among these places/addresses with radio buttons. So how can (or is it possible?) to post all the attributes the selected parcel shop (streetname, city, zipcode etc) and store it as the shipping address for the order? What i have now is something like this:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <% @parcel_shops.each do |parcel_shop| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :ship_address, parcel_shop do |ship_form| %>
      # This is the part that i need to change
      <%= ship_form.radio_button :attributes, parcel_shop.attributes 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit complicated, but thankfully there is a great example to go from in the spree_address_book extension.  The address book extension allows users to select one of their previously used addresses from a radio button, so that you don't have to enter all of the data again.

The key to how this works is in the checkout_controller_decorator and order decorator:

https://github.com/romul/spree_address_book/blob/master/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller_decorator.rb
https://github.com/romul/spree_address_book/blob/master/app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb

The before_filter in the checkout_controller sets the address params based on whether a normal address was input, or a radio button address selection was used.  The order decorator then accepts both forms of inputs.

If you're only accepting the one type of shipping address, you can simplify that down, but the code in that repo should help you figure out how to do it:

https://github.com/romul/spree_address_book/